# Using `quick-look` to find certain element

Tags: scala, quickselect

First of all, I want to say that this is a school assignment and I am only seeking for some guidance.

My task was to write an algorithm that finds the k:th smallest element in a seq using quickselect. This should be easy enough but when running some tests I hit a wall. For some reason if I use input `(List(1, 1, 1, 1), 1)` it goes into infinite loop.

Here is my implementation:

```
  val rand = new scala.util.Random()

  def find(seq: Seq[Int], k: Int): Int = {
    require(0 <= k && k < seq.length)        
    val a: Array[Int] = seq.toArray[Int]      // Can't modify the argument sequence

    val pivot = rand.nextInt(a.length)
    val (low, high) = a.partition(_ < a(pivot))
    if (low.length == k) a(pivot)
    else if (low.length < k) find(high, k - low.length)
    else find(low, k) 
  }
```

For some reason (or because I am tired) I cannot spot my mistake. If someone could hint me where I go wrong I would be pleased.

Comment: Walk through it in a debugger. But  a hint `a.partition(_ < a(pivot))` when all the elements are the same will always produce an empty `low` and original a in `high`

Comment: ohh, of course. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are depending on this line - `val (low, high) = a.partition(_ < a(pivot))` to split the array into 2 arrays. The first one containing the continuous sequence of elements smaller than pivot-element and the second contains the rest.

Then you say that if the first array has length `k` that means you have already seen `k` elements smaller that your pivot-element. Which means pivot-element is actually `k+1`th smallest and you are actually returning `k+1`th smallest element instead of `k`th. This is your first mistake.

Also... A greater problem occurs when you have all elements which are same because your first array will always have 0 elements.

Not only that... your code will give you wrong answer for inputs where you have repeating elements among `k` smallest ones like - `(1, 3, 4, 1, 2)`.

The solution lies in obervation that in the sequence (1, 1, 1, 1) the `4`th smallest element is the `4`th `1`. Meaning you have to use `<=` instead of `<`.

Also... Since the `partition` function will not split the array until your `boolean` condition is false, you can not use partition for achieving this array split. you will have to write the split yourself.